Vertical Alignment of Plots and Tables in Tabular Array
I want to display a plot, a table, and some text side by side and vertically centered. Here is my attempt using the tabular array package.
Here is what I have

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\pgfplotsset{
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    ylabel style={at={(axis cs:.5,-2.7)},anchor=north},
    minor tick num=1,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    %ticklabel style={fill=white},   % font=\normalsize
    xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    width=6cm, height=6cm, 
    domain = -2:2,
}
\newcommand{\plotA}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel = \(x\),
            ylabel = {\(y\)},
            ]
            %Below the red parabola is defined
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\tableA}{   
    {\begin{tblr}[t]{|c|c|}
            \hline
            l& o \\
            \hline
            r & e\\
            \hline
            m & i\\
            \hline
            p & s \\
            \hline
            u& m \\
            \hline
            d& o  \\
            \hline
        \end{tblr}
    }
}
\newcommand{\piecewiseA}{
lor
}

\begin{document}


        
        \begin{tblr}[t]{@{} Q[c,m] Q[c,m] Q[c,m] @{}} 
            \hline
            \plotA  & \tableA & lor \\
            \hline
        \end{tblr}
        
        
\end{document} 

Here is something closer to my desired result

I'd also like the row to span the width of the page, but maybe that's a seperate question.

Similar: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/481 which is resolved by setting \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=...], see the doc of baseline option for more info.

Similar questions was already asked, but now I haven't time to find it.  To solve your problem, you need to move image baseline to its vertical center and remove option for top align at table.
It is not clear, why you not write imag and table directly in main table:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=6cm, height=6cm, 
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=1,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    %ticklabel style={fill=white, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt},
    xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    domain = -2:2,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{@{} *{3}{ Q[c,m]} @{}} 
        \hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = \(x\),
        ylabel = {\(y\)},
        ]
        %Below the red parabola is defined
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    &   \begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            l& o \\
            \hline
            r & e\\
            \hline
            m & i\\
            \hline
            p & s \\
            \hline
            u& m \\
            \hline
            d& o  \\
            \hline
        \end{tblr}
        &   lor \\
    \hline
    \end{tblr}    
\end{document} 


If you for some reason like to insert diagram, table in text by use defined new command, than you only need to correct definitions as follows:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=6cm, height=6cm, 
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=1,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    %ticklabel style={fill=white, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt},
    xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    domain = -2:2,
}
\newcommand{\plotA}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel = \(x\),
            ylabel = {\(y\)},
            ]
            %Below the red parabola is defined
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\tableA}{   
    {\begin{tblr}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            l& o \\
            \hline
            r & e\\
            \hline
            m & i\\
            \hline
            p & s \\
            \hline
            u& m \\
            \hline
            d& o  \\
            \hline
        \end{tblr}
    }
}
\newcommand{\piecewiseA}{
lor
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{@{} *{3}{ Q[c,m]} @{}} 
        \hline
\plotA  & \tableA & lor \\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}    
\end{document} 

Result is the same as before.

Thank you! I found a few similar questions but nothing specific to plots. It looks like this is really a tikz question. I find tables more readable when the data is somewhere else.
